# Query latency client and server

Tags: java, mysql

I am a noob java and MySQL user. This is the first time i write a java program that implemented with MySQL database. I have question about why it has so much latency when i executes query in a client which is located at a different computer but in the same local network.

**My program structure:**

It is a restaurant POS application. My DB and my POS program is located at different computers. My queries commands are all built inside my program. My DB only have one schema and few tables. There are only few rows data that are stored in those tables.

**Problem:**

When I pressed a button in my program and ran a query and select a row from my DB, tt takes at least 1 sec to executed it and return me something. So i try move my program to the same computer as the Database server. It runs 10 times faster that before. OMG. what is going on.
I have no idea why it takes so much longer when the queries ran through a local network. Can someone explain me why and what is the alternative way to make it realtime if possible lol.

**My sample query code:**

```
  Connection co = null;
  PreparedStatement ps= null; 
  try{
        co = myconnection.getConnection();

        String insert = "INSERT INTO `R`.`order` (name, firstCourse, secondCourse,           thirdCourse, seafood, other, dessert, drink, price, quantity, note, type, position , time_in ,subtable, tid , aid ) ";
               insert += "VALUE ( '"+itemName+"','"+itemFirst+"','"+itemSecond+"','"+itemThird+"','"+itemSeafood+"','"+itemOther+"','"+itemDessert+"','"+itemDrink+"','"+itemPrice+"','"+num+"','"+notes+"','"+type+"','"+position+"','"+dateTime+"','"+subcheck+"','"+tableID+"','"+userID+"')";


        ps = co.prepareStatement(insert);
        ps.executeUpdate();
        this.updateJTable();

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("error occur when insert item:"+e);
    }finally{
            try {
                 ps.close();
                 co.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) { /* ignored */}
    }
```

this is my connection class:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class myConnection {
public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.2:3306/r";
    String user = "root"; 
    String pass = "";
    Connection connection = null;
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    try{
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
    }catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return connection;
}

public static void closeConnection(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    //if (connection != null && !connection.isClosed()) {         
        connection.close();
    //}
}
public  void closeRs(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException{
    //if (resultSet != null) {         
        resultSet.close();
    //}
}
public  void closePs(PreparedStatement preparedStatement) throws SQLException{
    //if (preparedStatement != null) {         
        preparedStatement.close();
    //}
}
}
```

Comment: Your code could be dangerous, you should use the `setX` method instead of adding the strings. As for your question, I expect it to be slower if it's on a network, did you try to ping the machine to see the result?

Comment: Do you use a connection pool, or do you create a new connection every time you need one? If the latter, then do the former. And +1 to Djon. The whole point of prepared statements is to bind parameters to make the code secure. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @Djon probably you're recommending OP to use `PreparedStatement` instead of simple `Statement`, but that's a security hole in its code, it won't solve the net latency problem.

Comment: If you have a SQL client such as Squirrel, try executing the command there. You'll come to know if it is a latency problem or issue with badly written code, for instance, not using a connection pool.

Comment: Also, if you use Hibernate, it handles caching of entities for you. Although you need to be wary of multiple applications writing to the same database in that case (maybe use Infinispan as 2LC).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza OP is already using `PreparedStatement`s, I was suggesting that he/she looks into a more reliable code. I have no idea if it could have an impact on performances, but I expect running it from the network would.

Comment: @Djon it won't but will solve the security problem.

Comment: i dun care much about security problem now. i just want to get rid of those latency.  btw is that mean i should use sth else beside PreparedStatement?

Comment: @user2021373. No. It means your query should use parameters (`insert into ... values (?, ?, ?, ...)`), and that you should set the parameters using `preparedStatement.setString(1, itemName); preparedStatement.setString(2, itemFirst);`. Besides security, if one of your parameters contain a single quote, your code will throw an exception because the query will be invalid. Bound parameters are correctly escaped by the driver.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Establishing a connection over a network is very expensive, the further the connection, the more expensive it is.

Instead I suggest keeping your connections or using a connection pool.  This will mean you spend more of your time performing the query or insert or update than you do creating a new connection.

Comment: Yes, there are pooled connection libs you can use to make this very simple (such as Apache Commons DBCP).

Comment: connection pool? sorry, i am a noob, i dun know what is that mean. and what excatlly is " create a new connection every time"?

Comment: is that mean i dun have to close the connection co until i am exiting the program or log out?

Comment: @user2021373 *create a new connection everytime* means your `myconnection.getConnection()` is implemented this way: `Class.forName(<driver_name>); return DriverManager.getConnection(<connection params>);`. Instead, a connection pool (which you should look on the net) will create a bunch of connections and keep them *sleeping* until you retrieve a connection from it, then the pool will *awake* one of them and give it to you, when you close this connection it will go back to *sleep* until is needed in the future or the application finishes.

Comment: A connection pool is a pool of connections.  try google for more details.  You create creating a new connection each time you insert something.  This is the expensive part which you want to avoid.  A simple way to do this is to create a connection once and use it for the life of the program. I think you mean `don't` not `dun` http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dun

Comment: sounds very clear now. i guess the problem is that i do not have a connection pool.